# PHP get value of all rows togeter

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have column `money` in my "Users" table and I need PHP to calculate the total number of money that all users have.

I know this counts rows but I don't know how to get the total number of money in game with PHP

```
<?php
$r = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `health`='100' AND `level`='1'");
$user = mysql_fetch_object($r);
echo"There are:<br>";
echo mysql_num_rows($r);
echo" Users in the database<br>";
echo"Total there are:<br>";
echo number_format($user->money); //I want it to calculate how much money there are inn the game but i cant find a way to do this
echo" Money inn the game<br>";
?>
```

I know I should go for MYSQLI or PDO but I'll start using that later.

Answer (score 3):

Why not query the database with:

```
SELECT SUM(`money`) FROM `users` WHERE `health`='100' AND `level`='1'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SUM()`. In this case MySQL will use implicit `GROUP BY` so you don't need to specify it. This will give you both number of users and total money in the game:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_users, SUM(money) AS total_money 
 FROM `users` 
 WHERE `health`='100' AND `level`='1';
```

To translate this into your PHP, you should be able to do:

```
<?php
$r = $sql->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_users, SUM(money) AS total_money FROM `users` WHERE `health`='100' AND `level`='1';");
$user = mysql_fetch_object($r);
echo"There are:<br>";
echo $user->num_users;
echo" Users in the database<br>";
echo"Total there are:<br>";
echo number_format($user->total_money); //I want it to calculate how much money there are inn the game but i cant find a way to do this
echo" Money inn the game<br>";
?>
```